WARNINGS: ?: (mysql.W002)
Estoy usando django con mariadb y estoy obteniendo este warning cada vez que inicio mi aplicacion o hago un test:
?: (mysql.W002) MariaDB Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'       
        HINT: MariaDB's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MariaDB, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly 
recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode

Tras ver la documentacion he intentado agregar esto a la configunarion de mysql de mi base de datos:
[mysqld]
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

He reiniciado mysql pero sigue apareciendo el warning

El warning que estás viendo indica que el Modo Estricto de MariaDB no está habilitado para la conexión de la base de datos de tu aplicación Django. Habilitar el Modo Estricto de MariaDB es importante porque ayuda a prevenir problemas de integridad de datos al convertir ciertas advertencias en errores, lo que puede ayudar a detectar problemas temprano durante la inserción de datos.
Para solucionarlo ademas de la configuración que has añadido al archivo my.ini o my.conf  debes indicar a django que el modo estricto esta activado, para ello en setings.py agrega lo siguiente en la configuración de la base de datos
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "OPTIONS": {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', innodb_strict_mode=1",
            }
    }
}

